# How to call a such swift function?

Tags: swift, function, parsing

```
/* Checks Is Username Already Exists
        Take - username
        Return - Bool (True/False) */

    func checkIsUserExists(username: String, completion: ((isUser: Bool?) -> Void)!) {

        var isPresent: Bool = false;

        let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "your_class_name")
        query.whereKey("your_key", equalTo:username)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                if (objects!.count > 0) {
                    isPresent = true;
                }

            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }

            completion(isUser: isPresent);
        }
    }
```

I found this function method that checks if the user exists in parse database but I dont get it what is the proper way to call it?
checkIsUserExists("user@gm.com, comletion.. ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires a closure that acts as a callback. So you'd call it in the following way:

```
checkIsUserExists("User Name"){isUser in if let user = isUser where user {
    userFound()
    }
else {
    userNotFound()
    }
}
```

Assuming you also had the following methods in place:

```
func userFound() {
// do something if the user was found
}

func userNotFound() {
// do something if the user was not found
}
```

The important keyword is `in`. Before the keyword, within the curly braces, I've named the value that is being captured `isUser`. It is a Bool as we can see from the method. And the closure is not required to return anything: `(isUser: Bool?) -> Void)!` hence the word `Void`. After the `in` keyword we can use the captured value to do whatever we wish with the optional true or false value. Here I call one of two functions.

In terms of code it is a very poor callback because while we know whether the user exists by the time the callback happens there might be several callbacks waiting in line and so we won't know which user exists because the user name is not passed to the closure.

You can find out plenty about [closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) in the Swift documentation.

Answer (score 0):

got it!
The correct way is

```
checkIsUserExists(userEmail.text!)
        {
            (isUser: Bool?) in
            print(isUser)
        }
```

WOW! what a weird function call

Comment: Check out 'Shorthand Argument Names' - you can call it like this: checkIsUserExists(userEmail.text!) { print($0) }